# Retrofit Jackson returning POJO with null members in onNext

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit, rx-android

I'm using Retrofit,  Jackson and Rx to make some web service calls.  This one endpoint is giving me trouble.  According to the Retrofit logs it's correctly making the POST request but when I subscribe to `onNext` the POJO is populated with null.

I've written several endpoints in an identical fashion and haven't had any trouble with them.  The only real difference with this one is that it is a bare JSON payload whereas the others were mapped to a List of values.

Here is the JSON as it appears in the logs:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "37437e46-d1a1-44fa-9a6a-ab92d7dd673f",
    "expires_in": 83191,
    "refresh_token": "4add01a5-bdc9-489e-87f3-ab8e19f2b6e5"
}
```

This is my POJO:

```
public class AccessToken {

    @JsonProperty(value = "token_type", required = true)
    public String tokenType;

    @JsonProperty(value = "access_token", required = true)
    public String accessToken;

    @JsonProperty(value = "expires_in", required = true)
    public int expiry;

    @JsonProperty(value = "refresh_token", required = true)
    public String refreshToken;

    ...
}
```

And the Retrofit request:

```
public class AuthenticationService {

private final LoginUserService mLoginUserService;

public interface LoginUserService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/access_token")
    Observable<AccessToken> loginUser(
            @Field("client_id") String clientId,
            @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
            @Field("username") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("grant_type") String grantType);

}

public AuthenticationService() {
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
    };

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Config.API_URL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    mLoginUserService =  restAdapter.create(LoginUserService.class);

}

public Observable<AccessToken> loginUser(String email, String password) {
    return mLoginUserService.loginUser(Config.CLIENT_ID, Config.CLIENT_SECRET, email, password, "password");
}

}
```

Comment: Isn't missing the .addConverterFactory(YOUR_CONVERTER) to the restAdapter instantiation?

Comment: @MartinoLessio thanks.   All I needed was to add `.setConverter(new JacksonConverter())` to the rest adapter.